# Grouping over 2 columns and use values of subsequent groups in calculations

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, grouping, summarize

Suppose I have a df with 3 columns, group1, group2 & variable

```
set.seed(1)
group1 = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5))
group2 = c("A","B","C","D","B","C","C","B","C","A","B","D")
variable = c(as.integer(rnorm(20,2)**3))
df=data.frame(group1, group2, variable)
```

I added the column 'min1' which states if the value of b within 'group1' is also present in group1(x-1). Vice Versa with plus1. Below the total data frame:

```
   group1 group2 variable min1 plus1
1       1      A        3    0     0
2       1      B       11    0     1
3       1      C        2    0     1
4       2      D       47    0     1
5       2      B       13    1     1
6       2      C        2    1     1
7       3      C       16    1     0
8       3      B       21    1     1
9       3      C       18    1     0
10      4      A        5    0     0
11      4      B       44    1     0
12      4      D       14    0     0
```

Now I want to do calculations such as max() and sum() (but also some more exotic ones) on the variables but not just on all values within their own group1 & group2 combination, but including the values of the group before (or after it). The min1 example is shown below.

```
  group1_min1 group2_min1 sum_min1 max_min1
1           2           B       24       13
2           2           C        4        2
3           3           C       36       18
4           3           B       34       21
5           4           B       65       44
```

Note that for group1_min1(3),group2_min1(C) three values are used: rows 6,7&9 (2,16&18).

I tried using group_by and summarize within dplyr, something like:

```
group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
summarize_each(funs(sum, max))
```

EDIT:

I found a solution to add the sum to the original df:

```
sum_min1 = c()
j=0
for (j in 1:(length(df$group1))){
  if (df[j,"min1"] == 0){sum_min1 = c(sum_min1,0)} else {
    sum_min1 = c(sum_min1,(sum(df[which((df[,"group1"] == df[j,"group1"] | df[,"group1"] == (df[j,"group1"]-1)) & df[,"group2"]==(df[j,"group2"])),"variable"])))
  }
}
df = cbind(df,sum_min1)
```

This delivers the output:

```
   group1 group2 variable min1 plus1 sum_min1
1         1    A        3    0     0       0
2         1    B       11    0     1       0
3         1    C        2    0     1       0
4         2    D       47    0     0       0
5         2    B       13    1     1      24
6         2    C        2    1     1       4
7         3    C       16    1     0      36
8         3    B       21    1     1      34
9         3    C       18    1     0      36
10        4    A        5    0     0       0
11        4    B       44    1     0      65
12        4    D       14    0     0       0
```

However this seems to be a very crude way and may take long on big data sets, also in reality there are multiple variables and multiple functions. Also it might be a problem because I want to do some user-defined functions which include a for loop for all the values.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

*Sorry for anything I do wrong, I am new to R and StackOverflow and not a native speaker.*

Comment: What is the value of b in `which states if the value of b within 'group1'`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `group1(x - 1)`? I don't understand your notation.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier if I change group2 in letters. 
If in the group1 (for example rows 1, 2 & 3 (all 1) or rows 4, 5, 6 (all 2)) there is a specific letter in group2 (for example df[6,2] = C) it checks if there is a C in df[1:3,2], since that group (with value 1) is one less than the group the C (of df[6,2]) which is 2. 
Row 11 is TRUE for this, since B is also in group1(with value 4-1=3 in row 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Data
set.seed(1)
group1 = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3))
group2 = c("A","B","C","D","B","C","C","B","C","A","B","D")
variable = c(as.integer(rnorm(12,2)**3))
df=data.frame(group1, group2, variable)
```

For the first part-

```
df$min1 <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x)
          {
           if(df[x, "group1"] == 1){0} else {
            max(df[x, "group2"] %in% df[df$group1 == df[x,"group1"] - 1,"group2"])}
          })

df$plus1 <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x)
          {
           if(df[x, "group1"] == max(df$group1){0} else {
            max(df[x, "group2"] %in% df[df$group1 == df[x,"group1"] + 1,"group2"])}
          })
```

Second part

```
df$sum_min1 <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x)
                {
                 if(df[x, "group1"] == 1){0}else{
                  sum(df[df$group1 == df[x,"group1"] & 
                         df$group2 == df[x,"group2"],"variable"],
                      df[df$group1 == df[x,"group1"] - 1 &
                         df$group2 == df[x,"group2"],"variable"])}
                 })
```

Comment: In the second part I want to do some functions over values in the column variables. The values they should take are the following:
 All values which have the same value of group2 within group 1 (so row 7 and 9 are both 'B' in group1 with value 3, their variable values are 16 & 18. However, the sum function should not only take those 2 in account, but also row 6, because it also has value B, but in a group one less than rows 7 & 9. The total sum should be 2+16+18.

It is also allowed to have a column with these calculations, but with zeros when min1 or plus1 is zero as well.

Comment: Check the updated script. Please mark the answer as correct if it works.